# Keycloak and Spring Boot: session creation policy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I try to configure keycloak with Spring Boot amd I would like to use custom Keycloak login page for getting acess token. Then I would like to pass this token to rest endpoints in my microservices. My Spring application is running on port 8081. I set up in keycloak admin console valid redirect as `http://localhost:8081/*`. Now during redirectin after login jsessionid is added to url (it looks like this `http://localhost:8081/;jsessionid=session_id`) and I am getting exception:

```
org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String ";"
```

After removal from Spring security configuration `sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)` it is redirected to valid url but `KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY` and `KEYCLOAK_SESSION` is not set in browser storage. I would like to as why does it work this way and what is proper way to configure it?

Part of my Spring security config:

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.
        csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy())
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .fullyAuthenticated();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take Keycloak sample spring boot application [app-authz-springboot](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/app-authz-springboot) and run it on localhost together with keycloak server - you fill find, indeed, it uses cookies `KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY` and `KEYCLOAK_SESSION` during authentication phase with IDM. These cookies are not required for your application, but since everything is running on your localhost you will see them all under "localhost" domain. After log-in you can safely delete them from storage and notice that your application runs smoothly.

For real deployments your IDM and application will be in different domains and you will not see these cookies. They are not required for your application. The only thing you need in fact is JSESSIONID.

Comment: In the scenario of real deployment, when IDM and application are in different domains, is there any way we can use cookies?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using session-based authentication (where the Keycloak access type is confidential and you are using SessionAuthenticationStrategy) then this approach works to get the token:

```
@GetMapping("/api/badges")
publicResponseEntity<List<Badges>>getAllBadges(
HttpServletRequestrequest,
HttpServletResponseresponse){


//SESSIONBASED
Var ctx2=(KeycloakSecurityContext) request.getAttribute(KeycloakSecurityContext.class.getName());
Var token=ctx2.getToken();
log.info("Name {} Email{}",token.getName(), token.getEmail());
```